# Terraform data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "version" attribute gives Error: "version": this field cannot be set

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I use data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" in Terraform to pull data from Azure Vault

Now I want to pull secret of specific version, I tried: `version = "719f0d55d1a04c6b862430e00d61b9ae"`

but it fails with Error: "version": this field cannot be set:

[image]

Comment: Terraform does not provide the property `version` for the data [`azurerm_key_vault_secret`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/key_vault_secret.html#argument-reference) currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [resource's documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/key_vault_secret.html#attributes-reference), `version` is an exported *attribute* not an *argument*. The difference is that attributes are used as resource outputs in other terraform code, e.g. `azurerm_key_vault_secret.var2.version`, whereas arguments are values that you're allowed to specify as inputs to the resource.